# SQL Find occurrences of value in a table regardless of columns

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I was recently asked in a interview how would I get count of apples, bananas and oranges in a table regardless of column information. The interviewer asked to provide counts of occurrences of apples and bananas and skip oranges..

I have never done a query before without column name, please help..

thx

Comment: Use column index,first column 1,....

Comment: That's because in a well designed database schema, you don't tend to have data randomly scattered across multiple columns. If two pieces of data are of the same "type", such that you'd want to compare them, add them together, or anything else, they really ought to both appear in the *same* column.

Comment: This may be silly.. Can we concatenate all the columns into single column and do a substr?

Answer (score 0):

Credits of [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046271/2899629) goes to @GordonLinoff. Assume that you have 5 columns in the table:

```
select col_value, count(*) cnt from
(select (case when cols.num = 1 then t.col_1
              when cols.num = 2 then t.col_2
              when cols.num = 3 then t.col_3
              when cols.num = 4 then t.col_4
              when cols.num = 5 then t.col_5
         end) as col_value
from table t cross join
(select level as num from dual connect by level <= 5) cols)
where col_value in ('Apple', 'Banana')
group by col_value
order by 1;
```

The table will be full-scanned but only once, thus it is more effective than `UNION ALL` of all column combinations. Also you can rewrite this query using column information from data dictionary and dynamic SQL so it would be applicable to any table and any number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would approach the issue. Note I used a table in the database I have the misfortune to support. Also this would need some modification and then one would need to query the table where rows were inserted.

```
declare @columnName nvarchar(128)
declare @command nvarchar(250)
--drop table interview_idiocy
create table interview_idiocy
(
    Column_name varchar(128),
    Fruit varchar(50)
)
declare interview_idiocy cursor for 
    select 
        column_name 
    from 
        information_schema.columns 
    where 
        table_name = 'People'
        AND data_type in ('varchar', 'char')

open interview_idiocy 
fetch next from interview_idiocy into @columnName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    set @command = 'insert interview_idiocy select count(' + @columnName +'),' + @columnName + ' from people where ' + @columnName + ' = ''apple'' group by ' + @columnName
    exec sp_executesql @command
    print @command
    fetch next from interview_idiocy into @columnName
end
close interview_idiocy
deallocate interview_idiocy
```

Comment: I guess that it is T-SQL whereas OP tagged the question as `oracle`. Also please use code formatting feature for better readability.